# mathematical 'not' of integer

Tags: delphi

Why delphi perform mathematical 'not' of integer rather than force to cast to boolean value in while do looping ?
Example

```
var myint:integer;
...
myint:=1;  
while not myint=5 do
begin
  myint:=myint+1;
  showmessage('myint now is : '+inttostr(myint));
end;
```

Comment: @sashkello: Wrong. `not myint=5` is calculating the binary complement of `myint` (that is the functionality of the `not` operator) and is then comparing this to `5`.

Comment: @alzaimer well, `not` is in fact two operators. Either logical or bitwise negation depending on the type of its operand.

Comment: Would be better to use `while myint <> 5 do`, or even `while myint < 5 do` if this is what you intended.

Comment: Interesting close voting here

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm voting against reopening because I can't figure out what in the world the OP means. Probably a reasonable question if it can be rephrased to make sense.

Comment: @chrylis It makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: @postgreat: Note that doing a not of a non-boolean, ie an integer, is often useful - and that answers your question why Delphi doesn't cast the int to boolean (not addressed by the answers below, I think?) Conceptually, if not of a boolean flips a single bit, then not of an integer flips each bit in that integer. This can be useful for bitmasks and other techniques.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your expression uses two operators: `not` and `=`. In order to understand how it is parsed you need to consult the table of [operator precedence](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_%28Delphi%29#Operator_Precedence).

```
Operators    Precedence
----------------------------
@            first (highest)
not
----------------------------
*            second
/
div
mod
and
shl
shr
as
----------------------------
+            third
-
or
xor
----------------------------
=            fourth (lowest)
<>
<
>
<=
>=
in
is
----------------------------
```

This shows that `not` has the highest precedence of all operators, and is of higher precedence than `=`. Which means that your expression is parsed as if it were:

```
(not myint) = 5
```

In this expression, because it is bound to an integral variable, `not` is *biwise negation*.

In order to get the result that you desire you must use parentheses to indicate that you wish to perform the equality test before the `not`:

```
not (myint = 5)
```

Now, in this expression, `(myint = 5)` is a logical expression and so the `not` operator is now *logical negation*.

The answer to a question of this nature is always found in the table of [operator precedence](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_%28Delphi%29#Operator_Precedence) and it will pay dividends to become familiar with this table. This table will tell you how any expression that omits parentheses is parsed.

Finally as Rudy points out, your specific expression is most cleanly written using the `<>` operator:

```
myint <> 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the list. I know is most cleanly written using the <> operator like TLama and Rudy said. But sometimes we use it accidently because we forget about operator precedence.

Comment: So in my code above, what happened is like `while (not myint)=5 do` (what really happened because of the operator precedence), rather than `while not (myint=5) do` (what I expected), right?

Answer (score 8):

The reason why delphi is doing this is that the `not` operator has a higher order than the equal comparison operator. It is an unary operator which is calculated first. In fact, is **has** to be calculated first before the `=` operator comes into action (which -of course- has the lowest order).

To force delphi calculating what you want, use parenthes:

```
if not (myint = 5) then....
// vs
if (not myint) = 5 then
// vs
if not myint = 5 then
```

As you know by now the latter two are equivalent.

BTW: Something similar (order precedence) happens with calculations like `3+4*5`. Here, the multiplication is carried out before the addition because the `*` operator has a higher order compared to the `+` operator.

Comment: I still wonder why no one proposes the obvious solution: `if myint <> 5 then`. Ok, the question is why myint is inverted instead of `not (myint = 5)`, but still, using `<>` avoids that problem.

Comment: @Rudy, that was my initial (now deleted) comment. And also [`msandiford, did`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22293371/mathematical-not-of-integer#comment33873431_22293371), but it's at most to be a comment.

Comment: Yes, of course, and that is why I wrote it in a comment. <g>

Comment: @RudyVelthuis and TLama too: I know that's the solution to avoid this problem. But I just want to know, why if i used that code (my code above) that's not working, I just want to know why.

Comment: @alzaimar : thanks for the answer. This is one of the best answer too and more easy to understand with 3+4*5 example.